# R static/offline documentation files

Tags: r

Is there a place where all R package help files can be found in a way browsable with the web browser (on a Linux system)?
Or a method how to generate all these somehow to be after that browsable?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user posted the same question twice

Comment: If you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/76797126/1783801 – these are two different questions. One (the other) asks for a program with interactive searching (and more), this one here asks for simple static local files. Separated both, as they handle different facettes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question was asking if there is a place where all R package help files can be found in a way browsable with the web browser (on a Linux system)? The answer is "no" in general, but the answer to your second question is "yes".  If you install a package from source with the `--html` install option, you'll get HTML help files built. You can do this with

```
install.packages("<pkg>", INSTALL_opts="--html", type="source")
```

They are installed in the directory `html` within the package directory, which you can find using

```
system.file("html", package = "<pkg>")
```

There are some differences from the usual help files which are rendered on demand, because help files can contain executable code that is run just before displaying them, but in most cases they are very similar.

However, this is rarely used, and you'll sometmes find broken links. For example, a package I just tried had a link saying "Package NEWS.", but it didn't link to the right place.  That's a bug in the code that generated the files, but it's unlikely anyone is going to put in the effort to fix it.

Comment: Yes, thats unfortunately a problem, that e.g. from `file:///usr/lib/R/library/MASS/html/00Index.html` no link to the packages function works in that files (or exists as html file), so they are not really useful.