# Standalone R help browser available?

Tags: r

Is there a possibility to have a local R package help browser active, independent from IDEs, including possibility to search for docs and in-page, potentially including possibility to store favorites?

Comment: is https://www.rdocumentation.org/ not sufficient?

Comment: It is not local, but a remote web page.

Comment: oh right! you want local in the sense of offline

Comment: there ought to be some way of finding the place where all help files are saved on the computer. I haven't been able to find it, but it should exist (assuming the help files aren't compressed into rds files)

Comment: yeah, I hoped there should be a way – but I could not find it :-)

Comment: 1) download the complete online repository.   2) stay online.  Otherwise, for obvious reasons you won't have access to the existing man page documents.    Frankly, I don't see the point since if you don't run R from either a gui or the command line, you'd have to write your own interpreter to dive into the  `R/library/package_name` directories and pull out the .Rd documents

Comment: Is it available for download? Still "all 26.883 R packages on CRAN and Bioconductor" from RDocumentation would probably be a bit much. Documentation for just my installed packages would be quite sufficient.

Comment: @Mark:  normally the help files are stored in `rds` files in the `help` directory of the installed package.  They are stored as parsed versions of the `Rd` files, and the HTML is generated on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `help.start()` in an R session you'll be able to have a browser with some of those capabilities as long as that session is running.  Help pages are generated on demand, so you need the R process to be running to do the work.

The searching is very old-fashioned.  It's similar to what you get in the console with `??pattern`, but with a few more options.  I haven't used it in years, but I tried it just now, and it appeared to work.

Storing favourites isn't an option in R, but maybe you could set bookmarks in your browser.  Normally they won't work in a new session, because R serves the pages on a particular port number, and that changes every time.  However, you can ask for a particular port when you run `help.start()`, and you'll get it if it is not in use.

EDITED to add:

Based on your comment:  If you just want help available but don't want it to start right away, you can use

```
options(help.ports=<vector of possible port numbers>)
tools::startDynamicHelp()
```

Also setting

```
options(help_type = "html")
```

means that that R session will use the help system you just started.

Comment: This fits very well for what I need, thanks. Adding `options(help.ports=c(10018,10019,10020,10021,10022)); tools::startDynamicHelp(); options(help_type = "html")` to my `.Renviron` ensures the help files are accessible via web browser at `http://127.0.0.1:10018/doc/html/index.html` (or the later ports from list for further parallel sessions) every time I start R (also without a manual `help.start()`) and also that the browser/html version is called if starting help in R console like `?lm`. Can live with varying port of the subsequent sessions. (FTR: Rstudio help also still works normally.)